# Error al leer Excel en paquete SSIS

Tags: ssis

Tengo el siguiente problema, resulta que quiero sacar desde un Excel informacion y enviarla a una tabla en SQL Server, en mi maquina funciona bien pero al pasarla a la maquina de Desarrollo los componentes SSIS al ejecutar el paquete arroja el siguiente error.

Excel carga Tabla TMP_tblBCOMFallecidos:Error: SSIS
Error Code
DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNE
CTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to
the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"
failed with error code 0xC0209302. There may be error
messages posted before this with more information on
why the AcquireConnection method call failed

Alguien puede ayudar en esto.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.